# Laravel: laravel.log permission denied

Tags: php, macos, laravel

When I try to open my Laravel app I get the following error:

```
UnexpectedValueException 
The stream or file "/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: 
failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write the following within terminal and ensure you are in the projects directory:

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*`

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/storage

its Not work

Comment: @MasoudKhani, are you running `php artisan serve`? If so, restart it. I know the above works 100% as I have to do it frequently when developing locally ^_^

Comment: log: No such file or directory The Error is This In Terminal

Comment: CD into the projects directory within terminal and paste the above. You need to be within the directory before running the code.

Comment: usage: chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
 chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...





is it Work Now!?
But Also The Error In it

Comment: uh what?? you just need to paste: `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*` once you're in the root of your projects directory. If you're running `php artisan serve` you need to stop that and restart after you chmod the folder / files.

Comment: Take care you are within the path:

<XAMP_INSTALLATION>/xamppfiles/htdocs/<APP>/

Answer (score 0):

on FINDER right clic on STORAGE *(inside ::your disk:: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel)*  folder and go to INFORMATION, go to bottom SHARING AND PERMISSIONS, there you must give READ AND WRITE permissions to EVERYONE. This option worked for me

NOTE: my OS languaje is SPANISH, may be text have some little variations; please, excuse my  english

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you have installed Cent OS have to disable selinux.

## setenforce 0

it will works.