# The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apcjobs/storage/logs/laravel-2020-06-06.log" could not be opened:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

full error: The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apcjobs/storage/logs/laravel-2020-06-06.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Does anybody know why do I get this error?
 I have a Mac, and I have transfered a project from windows

Comment: The reason you're getting this error is because the process that is trying to access the file doesn't have permission to do so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131156/laravel-laravel-log-permission-denied should point you in the right direction.

Comment: you need to give permission to storage folder.